# scheduler fetch data every midnight

Tags: go

how to add a scheduler with a specific time so that the application can synchronize data at a specified time

```
addCron, _ := time.LoadLocation("Asia/Jakarta")
scheduler := cron.New(cron.WithLocation(addCron))

defer scheduler.Stop()

scheduler.AddFunc("10 00 * * 1-6", ExecuteRoutine)

// start scheduler
go scheduler.Start()
done := make(chan bool)

// trigger shutdown
sig := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
signal.Notify(sig, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
<-sig
done <- true
```

function and endpoint that will collect automatically at the midnight

```
httpRouter.Post("/master/upsertIntoServices", services.UpsertIntoServices)
```

how to add that endpoint into a function `ExecuteRoutine`, so it can do a cron job every midnight

Comment: please specify the following: 1) which cron library you are using; 2) how is `ExecuteRoutine` defined; 3) where `httpRouter` comes from; 4) what you mean with "add that endpoint"

Comment: 1.  cron "github.com/robfig/cron/v3"
2. http Router come from chi router 
I accommodate in one variable var (
 httpRouter router.Router          = router.NewChiRouter() )

Comment: the endpoint is taken from the http router

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is a simple example, to scheduler jobs at midnight from your code

```
addCron, _ := time.LoadLocation("Asia/Jakarta")
scheduler := cron.New(cron.WithLocation(addCron))

defer scheduler.Stop()

scheduler.AddFunc("@midnight", ExecuteRoutine)

// start scheduler
scheduler.Start()
```

You can discover, more information here in the [doc](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/robfig/cron?utm_source=godoc#section-documentation)

Only a few reminders:

- You don't need to run a goroutine when will call the command start.
- you do need to stop your scheduler at some point in your logic